# Shell alias/function with backticks

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line

I'm trying to write some kind of a shortcut in shell for the following command that I use quite often:

```
kill -9 `lsof -i :8080 | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

It lists the processes that are using the port `8080` and kills them. The process ID is written in the second word of the second line of the `lsof` output, that's why I need that ugly piping and execution.

I'm on Mac so I put an alias in `~/.profile`, but it obviously didn't work because of single/double quotes and backticks mix:

```
alias fport="kill -9 `lsof -i :8080 | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

after several tries with escaping stuff I decided to create a function in profile file:

```
function fport {
  kill -9 `lsof -i :8080 | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
}
```

But this didn't work for me either - keep getting strange outputs of process ID and the process is never killed.

Can someone help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Using `set -x` to trace execution of your function is a good place to start. (I have nitpicks, but none of them would explain the problem at hand).

Comment: *keep getting strange outputs of process ID* is not a sufficient description of the error.

Comment: Show output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: (Nitpick A: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re `function`; nitpick B: [BashFAQ #82](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) re backticks; but neither of those relates to the problem -- `set -x` is still the right place to start to track that down).

Comment: (also think about using `tee` to inspect copies of the data moving through your pipeline)

Comment: I don't think this will solve your issue but since you are using `awk`, you might avoid the pipe to `head` and `tail` via `awk 'FNR==2 {print $2}' < <(lsof -i :8080)`, in fact you may be able to refactor to `awk 'FNR==2 {system("kill -9" $2)}' < <(lsof -i :8080)`

Comment: `kill` or `kill -3` should be sufficient. `kill -9` doesn't give the process a chance to clean up before exiting, and should only be used during development to kill misbehaving processes.